# Error: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied when converted to Kotlin from Java

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, android-bitmap, rx-kotlin

*I have seen other questions here related to this error but still not able to fix. Plus I'm asking this question because unlike other questions here, I'm getting this error only when I convert the code to Kotlin from Java.*

I'm using this same RxJava code in Java, it works fine. 
I converted to Kotlin and it gives this error -

> Kotlin Compilation Error : None of the following functions can be
>   called with the arguments supplied

```
var observable : Observable<Bitmap> = Observable.just(bitmap)

var observer:Observer<Bitmap> = Observer<Bitmap>() {
                fun onSubscribe(d: Disposable) {
                    disposable = d
                }
                fun onNext(orientedBitmap:Bitmap) {
                    // do something
                }
                fun onError(e:Throwable) {
                }
                fun onComplete() {

                }
            }

observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())

          // It shows the error here
          .subscribe(observer)
```

Can anyone explain what's wrong here?

Comment: Are you missing `override` in the subscribe, onNext..Etc?

Comment: Is there more information on the error? Like which following functions are listed?

Comment: Solved it. It was a conflict in importing package. I'm also using Observer from architecture components.

Answer (score 1):

It was a conflict in importing package. I'm also using **Observer** from architecture components. Import Observer of both the packages, it will be solved.

So, for this -

`var observer:Observer<Bitmap> = Observer<Bitmap>()`

It was taking the Observer from the architecture components.

I solved it by using it like this -

```
var observer = object : io.reactivex.Observer<Bitmap>
```